# UDP socket programming in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

In socket programming, we have a client and a server. Client sends Register() request to server and server responds with RegisterAck(). Now we also want to send ChangeNotify() from server to client whenever there is a  manual change by user/admin in configuration file at server side. So is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember IP address and port of the client computer that had sent the register message. Then you can send messages from server to client at any time.
For testing purposes I suggest TCPView (from Sysinternals Suite) and 'hercules' from HW group.